# [Js]Работа с txt вывод строки

Tags: javascript, txt

Ребят, помогите.

Подскажите как сделать так чтобы софт брал первую строку из txt выводил юзеру и удалял из этого файла.

Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 2):

Открыть файл на чтение;

Вывести первую строку на экран;

Считать остальное в переменную;

Открыть файл на запись;

Записать текст из переменной.